# How can I adjust the preferred WiFi order?

Tags: wireless

I am using 13.04 Ubuntu. I want to make order on multiple wireless access.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: following up on your post...can you please explain a bit more ? What do you mean by 'order' ? From what i know there is no such thing as an 'order', this means that when you turn-on your wi-fi receiver the system tries to login to one of the available wi-fi networks. Best regards,
Panagiotis Mamatsis.

Comment: That is not true, many wireless managers will offer the option to order networks by preference so that even if one network offers better signal ration you can specify you preference to be connected to a certain access point. Think the network manager in Ubuntu used signal strength always as the wireless network preference order.

Comment: I just made all but one, to not connect automatically; that is useful if your infrastructure is not complex.

Answer (score 5):

You may find [this blog](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/wifi-radar-simple-tool-to-manage-wireless-profiles.html) helpful about an app called wifi radar that can create profiles for networks.

> WiFi Radar is a Python/PyGTK2 utility for managing WiFi profiles.It enables you to scan for available networks and create profiles for your preferred networks. At boot time, running WiFi Radar will automatically scan for an available preferred network and connect to it. You can drag and drop your preferred networks to arrange the profile priority.

You will require your root password to use the program. Once opened it should detect any available networks. You should then be able to drag and drop your preferred networks to arrange the profile priority as you wish.

You can download through the [Ubuntu software centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wifi-radar/) or at [this website](http://wifi-radar.tuxfamily.org). Another option to install is to open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install wifi-radar`

You can access the full user manual is available [here](http://wifi-radar.wikispot.org/User_Manual)

Comment: for instance you have two wireless which you can able to connect all of them ( wireless name x, y) it connects automatically to x after every boot. i want my pc to connect y instead of x. I am changing wireless manually after every boot of the pc. I want y to be a preffered one.

Comment: Have you tried to order them within wifi-radar so as that y is the preferred profile?

Comment: yes, I tried it but I could not find the options to change its order.

Comment: According to the wifi radar website you drag and drop your wifi profiles into the order you want them. This is a link to their user manual http://wifi-radar.wikispot.org/User_Manual